API Call with custom Body in dart flutter
I'm trying to call an API with a custom Body but I always the same error.
Error 400
And the API return "can't json/yaml decode the argument"
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:http/http.dart' as http;
import 'dart:developer' as developer;
Future\<dynamic\> ApiDiolos() async {
final mapHeader = {
'Accept': 'application/json',
'Content-Type': 'application/json',
'X-Diolos-Key':
'My-Custom-API-Key'
};
Uri uri = Uri.parse("https://api.diolos.com/myapipage.php");
var customBody = {};
customBody\["action"\] = "6";
customBody\["limit"\] = "null";
customBody\["offset"\] = "0";
final response = await http.post(uri,
headers: mapHeader,
body: json.encode(customBody.toString()),
encoding: Encoding.getByName('utf-8'));
}
void main() {
ApiDiolos();
}


Everything works fine with postman.
I hope you could help my with this issue.

just print the output of json.encode(customBody.toString()), in terminal and see what exactly you're doing !

I have this output. flutter: JSON encode Only : "{action: 6, limit: null, offset: 0}"

Pass the map variable directly to be encoded:
From
body: json.encode(customBody.toString()),

To
body: json.encode(customBody),

after that make sure the following:

You are using an authorized API Key.
You are calling the correct URL, it's preferable to test it before
integrating the call within your app.
Wait for the results of the call.

Look at the following code, and try to refactor it:
Future<Map?> ApiDiolos() async {
  final mapHeader = {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'X-Diolos-Key': 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' // provide an authorized key
  };
  Uri uri = Uri.parse(
      "https://api.diolos.com/myapipage.php"); // make sure it's a correct URL

  var customBody = {"action": "6", "limit": "null", "offset": "0"};

  final response =
      await http.post(uri, headers: mapHeader, body: json.encode(customBody));

  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    return json.decode(response.body);
  }
  return null;
}

void main() async {
  print(await ApiDiolos()); // you must wait for the Future to get completed
}


Hi, Same behavior, same error message. Thank you.

@Olivier ok, look at updates.

I verified all things but with your code this output is null. The key is good and url as well. The test with postman works fine ;) the JSON with postman return something like that : {
"error": 0,
"result": [
{
"id": 1,
"name": "String1"
}, ....... }
